# Infinity Limit problem

Tags: calculus, limits

This limit I tried to solve it but I can't I use l'Hospital but it didn't work. Could anyone help me to solve it? 
The limit is :
$$ \lim \limits_{n\to \infty }\frac{n^{2}+3^{n}}{n^{n}+ 2^{n}} =? $$

Comment: It is I think fairly clear that for large $n$ the bottom is much bigger than the top. Maybe to be formal divide top and bottom by $n^n$,

Answer (score 3):

For sufficiently large $n$, we have $n^2+3^n < 2 \cdot 3^n < 3 \cdot 3^n =3^{n+1} < 3^{2n} < 9^n$ and $n^n + 2^n > n^n$. So $$\frac{n^2+3^n}{n^n+2^n} < \frac{9^n}{n^n} < \frac{9^n}{18^n} = \frac{1}{2^n}$$ for $n \geq 18$. on the other hand, we are dividing two positives, so it is clearly greater than zero. So $$0 =\lim_{n\to\infty} 0 \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^2+3^n}{n^n+2^n} \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}=0$$

**Moral:** First check whether the numerator is growing much faster than the denominator of vice versa. Then the limit will equal 0 or $\pm \infty$. That can you usually prove using inequalities and the Squeeze theorem. If that doesn't work, then you can think about using l'Hôpital.

Comment: That is really an obvious solution..  but one question please.. this inequality how we prove it  $n^2+3^n < 2 \cdot 3^n$?

Comment: @user257567 For $n>2$, $n^2<3^n$. That is easy to show.

Comment: E.g. Taylor series. For $n\geq2$: $$3^{n-1} > e^{n-1} > 1+(n-1)+\frac{(n-1)^2}{2} = \frac{1}{2}n^2 +\frac{1}{2}$$ Thus $$3^n > \frac{3}{2}n^2 +\frac{3}{2} > n^2$$ Though it is a well known fact that the exponential function grows faster than any polynomial. I suspect you may use it.

Comment: @wythagoras thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$
0 \leq \lim \limits_{n\to \infty }\frac{n^{2}+3^{n}}{n^{n}+ 2^{n}} \leq 
\lim \limits_{n\to \infty }\frac{n^{2}+3^{n}}{n^{n}} = 
\lim \limits_{n\to \infty }\left(n^{2-n} + \left( \frac 3n \right)^n\right)
$$

Comment: So the answer is $0$?

Comment: @user257567 Exactly.

Comment: @wythagoras thanks

Answer (score 0):

The limit is $0$:

$\frac{n^{2}+3^{n}}{n^{n}+ 2^{n}}<\frac{n^{2}+3^{n}}{n^{n}}<n^{2-n}+\left ( \frac{3}{n} \right )^{n}$ and this last item is less than $n^{2-n}+\left ( \frac{3}{4} \right )^{n}$ as soon as $n\geq 4$. Now observe that both of these terms $\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$